# PDO last insert id returns null or no method found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ive been searching for long time some solution but none of them are working, tried all the topics from stackoverflow and nothing.

This is my connection script:

```
private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        $this->_pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is my method to query:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I had to redone my account activation system and put activation codes to separate table, so when new user come and register i need to grab insert id to place in activation codes table under `user_id`. The problem is i dont know how to alter script i provided to be able to grab that id.

I tried `$this->_pdo->lastInsertId();`

and `$this->_db->lastInsertId();`

in first case i get null all the time in second case i get no method `lastInsertId()` been found in class

maybe i place it in wrong place or do it wrong, help would be nice, thank you in advance;)

btw im using pdo under mysql server

Comment: Is it definitely inserting into the database?

Comment: If so, try `$this->_query->lastInsertId();`

Comment: This is what will happen in that case, yes i am inserting for sure. `Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId() in /APP/classes/DB.php`

Comment: Which to me confirms that `$this->_pdo->lastInsertId();` is the call that you want, and as it returns null, brings me back to my first question

Comment: can you please tell, where exactly in the code i should type this line so it will works? beacuse insert is made i check in db, new row is being added yet it returns 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($this->_query->execute()) {
    $id = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: lastInsertId returns the Id, what is the point if you dont store the return value in a variable?

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with your project.